# How do I fix the "You don't have write permissions into the /usr/bin directory" error when installing Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to install Rails 3 on a brand new MacBook Pro running OS X 10.6.3, Ruby 1.8.7, and Rails 2.3.5 and I'm wondering if I've hosed myself.  So far, I've run these commands:

```
$ gem update --system
$ gem install arel tzinfo builder memcache-client rack rack-test rack-mount erubis mail text-format thor bundler i18n
$ gem install rails --pre
```

However, when I run the last command, I get this error:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions into the /usr/bin directory.
```

I think it wants me to run the command with `sudo` so that it can write over `/usr/bin/rails`.  But if I do that, won't I be overwriting my Rails 2.3.5 executable?  I don't want to do that.  Instead, I'd like to keep both versions of Rails.  How do I do that?

Comment: I was getting same error on first command, use this command `sudo gem update --system -n /usr/local/bin`

Comment: What is the -n?

Comment: Just going to put it out here that simply restarting the terminal solved this for me.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'd suggest using [RVM](https://rvm.io/) it allows you have multiple versions of Ruby/Rails installed with gem profiles and basically keep all your gems contained from one another. You may want to check out a similar post [How can I install Ruby on Rails 3 on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916229/how-can-i-install-ruby-on-rails-3-on-osx)

Comment: only doing that solved for me a similar problem with the same error message

Comment: It seems RVM project (or link at least) is outdated

Answer (score 660):

use `-n` parameter to install like for cocoapods:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods -n /usr/local/bin
```

Comment: Why would we even need this?

Comment: Fails on MacOS unless you specify -n /usr/local/bin. Thanks for the solution

Comment: What does -n means?

Comment: according to http://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/#gem-install, -n specifies the directory where binaries are located. I also needed `-n /usr/local/bin` on my Mac. I ran `which pod` to determine its existing location before using the -n option which was indeed /usr/local/bin

Comment: I'm sure RVM is great, but this is a better answer that directly addresses the immediate problem without sending me down a rabbit hole.

Comment: thanks so much this works, but do we have to write -n /usr/local/bin for every gem installation??

Comment: Can't agree with you more. I suggest we always remember the option `-n /usr/local/bin` because `/usr/bin` belongs to the system, instead of to the end user.

Answer (score 117):

Using the **-n /usr/local/bin** flag does work, BUT I had to come back to this page every time I wanted to update a package again. So I figured out a permanent fix for this.

For those interested in fixing this **permanently**:

Create a ~/.gemrc file

```
vim .gemrc
```

With the following content:

```
:gemdir:
   - ~/.gem/ruby
install: -n /usr/local/bin
```

Now you can run your command normally without the -n flag.

Enjoy!

Comment: `vim .gemrc`
how to write this cmd

Comment: I am not sure this will work in Window$, but I guess you could use Notepad.

Comment: Thank you, just like you I was tired of looking for this suffix everytime I needed to make an update!

Answer (score 96):

```
sudo gem install cocoapods --pre -n /usr/local/bin
```

This works for me.

Comment: I had this issue and this answer worked for me! I replaced `cocoapods` with the dependency that I needed

Comment: Worked for me also with macOS Big Sur 11.6.1

Answer (score 39):

You can use `sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods`

This works for me.

Answer (score 8):

On macOS High Sierra, this solved my issue:

```
sudo gem update --system -n /usr/local/bin/gem
```

Comment: Worked for me with `/usr/local/bin` (without `/gem`)

Answer (score 7):

To fix your specific error you need to run that command as sudo, ie:

```
sudo gem install rails --pre
```

Comment: NO. Use rvm or rbenv ...do not just sudo.

Answer (score 6):

This Error hit me after installing RVM correctly.
Solution: re-boot Terminal.

Reference [RailsCast's RVM Install](http://railscasts.com/episodes/200-rails-3-beta-and-rvm) tutorial.

Comment: Not exactly 7 years later, but this works also if you're working on windows bash subsystem. Just exit the bash and launch it again. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For me, something different worked, that I found in on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2939169/3294286) from a similar question. Probably won't help OP, but maybe someone like me that had a similar problem.

**You should indeed use rvm**, but as no one explained to you how to do this **without rvm**, here you go:

```
sudo gem install tzinfo builder memcache-client rack rack-test rack-mount \
  abstract erubis activesupport mime-types mail text-hyphen text-format   \
  thor i18n rake bundler arel railties rails --prerelease --force
```

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**: Performing some operations such as `bundle installation` / `npm install` on docker container prompts a *lack of permissions error* and preventing us accomplish applicative tasks. By default docker containers are "unprivileged" and not allow to accomplish out of scope administrator capabilities.

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /usr/local/bundle directory.
```

**Solution**: Use `--previliged` flag  to enable all devices and allow the container nearly all the same access to the host as processes running outside containers on the host. **Pay attention** this might be a security issue under some circumstances and recommended only on test/staging/development environments.

> By default, Docker containers are “unprivileged” and cannot, for example, run a Docker daemon inside a Docker container. This is because by default a container is not allowed to access any devices, but a “privileged” container is given access to all devices (see the documentation on cgroups devices).
>
> When the operator executes `docker run --privileged`, Docker will enable
> access to all devices on the host as well as set some configuration in
> AppArmor or SELinux to allow the container nearly all the same access
> to the host as processes running outside containers on the host.
> Additional information about running with `--privileged` is available on
> the Docker Blog.

For additional reading about **Runtime privilege and Linux capabilities** read this [Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-and-linux-capabilities).

Answer (score 1):

Following the instructions in this answer helped me:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/72094586/755451

Essentially I think its down to the mentioned steps:

Step 2 Add the following lines to your .zshrc file

export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init - zsh)"
Step 3

brew update && brew upgrade ruby-build