# How to downgrade or install an older version of Cocoapods

Tags: ios, ruby, rubygems, cocoapods

How can I downgrade Cocoapods to an older version, or how can I install an older version of Cocoapods?

Answer (score 919, accepted):

to remove your current version you could just run:

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
```

you can install a specific version of cocoa pods via the following command:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods -v 0.25.0
```

You can use older installed versions with following command:

```
pod _0.25.0_ setup
```

Comment: To see which version you currently have, run `sudo gem list cocoapods`

Comment: This is brilliant! I had upgraded to 0.38, and with that version I was getting errors. All I had to do to revert to 0.37 was run your comment `sudo gem uninstall cocoapods` and then pick 0.38 from the automatically presented list. Within seconds I was back on 0.37, and my pod install worked again! Thanks so much!

Comment: Great thx! Just one comment, if you are using rvm, omit the sudo since its going to uninstall/install in the usr/bin instead of your rvm installation directory

Comment: Update... if you call `gem uninstall cocoapods` it will now ask you which version you want to uninstall. Much quicker! :o)

Comment: Cocoapods 1.0.0 Update:  note that if you have 1.0.0 installed, attempting to reinstall an older version on top will leave 1.0.0 as the default version, so you have to `sudo gem uninstall cocoapods` first, then select 1.0.0 as the version to remove.  Not sure if this has always been the behavior, but `sudo gem install cocoapods -v 0.39.0` alone didn't do the trick for me once I had 1.0.0.

Comment: If you see the error message "You don't have write permissions for the /usr/bin directory." on macOS High Sierra, use: `sudo gem install cocoapods -v 1.3.1 -n /usr/local/bin`

referenced from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893889/how-do-i-fix-the-you-dont-have-write-permissions-into-the-usr-bin-directory?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: You can also remove a specific version of cocoapods like: `sudo gem uninstall cocoapods -v 1.7.5 `.

This is specially useful if you want to revert to an older version as removing the current/latest version reverts it back to last installed version. If there is no other version installed you can installed the one you want like: `sudo gem install cocoapods -v 1.6.0`

Answer (score 104):

Actually, you don't need to downgrade – if you need to use older version in some projects, just specify the version that you need to use after `pod` command.

```
pod _0.37.2_ setup
```

Comment: Thanks, it kind of worked, but I had some ruby cocoapods-rome warnings so I ended up uninstalling cocoapods completely and installing only the older version.

Comment: I think this is a much better solution. There are unfortunate situations where you need different versions of cocoa pods for different projects and it's convenient to not have to uninstall and reinstall cocoa pods each time

Comment: This doesn't work for me, neither `pod _0.39.0_ install`. If I run that and then run `pod --version` it still shows the latest version.

Comment: you have to first install it with `sudo gem install cocoapods -v 0.39.0` , it will work after that

Comment: I can confirm that this doesn't work. Even with the required version installed, Cocoapods ignores the version specified and uses the latest installed version.

Comment: Just got it to work. I completely uninstalled all traces of cocoapods (using `gem list --local` as a guide), then installed cocoapods with `sudo gem install cocoapods -n /usr/local/bin`. Now, doing `pod _1.5.3_ install` uses 1.5.3 instead of the latest 1.8.0, even with both installed.

Answer (score 42):

Several notes:

Make sure you first get a list of all installed versions. I actually had the version I wanted to downgrade to already installed, but ended up uninstalling that as well. To see the list of all your versions do:

```
sudo gem list cocoapods
```

Then when you want to delete a version, specify that version.

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods -v 1.6.2
```

You could remove the version specifier `-v 1.6.2` and that would delete all versions:

You may try all this and still see that the Cocoapods you expected is still installed. If that's the case then it might be because Cocoaposa is stored in a **different directory**.

```
sudo gem uninstall -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods -v 1.6.2
```

Then you will have to also install it in a different directory, otherwise you may get an error saying **You don't have write permissions for the /usr/bin directory**

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods -v 1.6.1
```

To check which version is your default do:

```
pod --version
```

For more on the directory problem see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49213136/5175709)

Comment: Great extra detail about the alternative install folders – I needed that, thank you.

Answer (score 35):

If you need to install an older version (for example 0.25):

```
pod _0.25.0_ install
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. If I run this and the run `pod --version` it still shows the latest version.

Comment: `pod --version` will always show the newest version.
Use the example above to install an older version (in the example above the older version is 0.25.0)

Comment: In my case using `pod _1.5.3_ install` has the behavior of the new 1.7.x versions, so I'm really questioning about the reliability of this syntax…

Comment: This DOES work. I was able to use 1.7.5 while my latest version was 1.8.4.

Answer (score 26):

```
PROMPT> gem uninstall cocoapods

Select gem to uninstall:
 1. cocoapods-0.32.1
 2. cocoapods-0.33.1
 3. cocoapods-0.36.0.beta.2
 4. cocoapods-0.38.2
 5. cocoapods-0.39.0
 6. cocoapods-1.0.0
 7. All versions
> 6
Successfully uninstalled cocoapods-1.0.0
PROMPT> gem install cocoapods -v 0.39.0
Successfully installed cocoapods-0.39.0
Parsing documentation for cocoapods-0.39.0
Done installing documentation for cocoapods after 1 seconds
1 gem installed
PROMPT> pod --version
0.39.0
PROMPT>
```

Comment: This works. Fastlane detects the older version of the cocoapods. which leads to error.

Answer (score 7):

In my case I had to uninstall from homebrew

```
brew uninstall cocoapods
```

Answer (score 7):

For brew installed version

One way to fetch a specific version is as follows:

First, you'll probably want to uninstall cocoapods:

`brew uninstall cocoapods`

Find a suitable cocoapods.rb e.g. by browsing the repo -> https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/6b1477715df13e0ec4305c3420ac0c024867d34a/Formula/c/cocoapods.rb

For cocoapods 1.14.3:

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/6b1477715df13e0ec4305c3420ac0c024867d34a/Formula/c/cocoapods.rb  # or just download it 

brew install -s cocoapods.rb
```

Answer (score 4):

Note that your pod specs will remain, and are located at ~/.cocoapods/ .
This directory may also need to be removed if you want a completely fresh install.

They can be removed using `pod spec remove SPEC_NAME` then `pod setup`

It may help to do `pod spec remove master` then `pod setup`

Answer (score 3):

In some cases, one needs to remove some hidden artefacts in the home directory so that the up- or downgrade takes effect:

```
rm -rf ~/.cocoapods
```