# Reference is not a tree: f0a7...3e8c during cocoapods install

Tags: git, cocoapods, typhoon

After creating a new project in Xcode, I added

```
pod 'Typhoon', :head
```

to my Podfile. When trying to install the pod, I get the following error:

```
MacbookPro:MyNewProject myuser$ pod install
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing Typhoon (HEAD based on 2.2.1)
[!] /usr/bin/git submodule update --init --depth 1

Submodule 'Source/Vendor/OCLogTemplate' (https://github.com/typhoon-framework/OCLogTemplate.git) registered for path 'Source/Vendor/OCLogTemplate'
Cloning into 'Source/Vendor/OCLogTemplate'...

fatal: reference is not a tree: f0a76376a6b13b014b2785f54f106b84ebc83e8c

Unable to checkout 'f0a76376a6b13b014b2785f54f106b84ebc83e8c' in submodule path 'Source/Vendor/OCLogTemplate'
```

The cocoapods version is:

```
MacbookPro:MyNewProject myuser$ pod --version
0.34.0
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems there was a bug in Cocoapods 0.34.0 .

I upgraded to Cocoapods 0.34.1 and the install works correctly.

Comment: I updated cocoapods recently and got the same error (which I didn't get before). I updated to 0.34.1 but it did not resolve the issue, did you do anything else beside upgrading cocoapods?

Comment: I only updated using `sudo gem install cocoapods` and then `pod install` worked with no errors. Try downgrading to an older version of cocoapods, maybe that will help, see the [command here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20487849/downgrading-or-installing-older-version-of-cocoapods).

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error when I was trying to install a pod which name was changed, all I had to do was to use the new pod name.

In some macs didnt get the error because cocoapods cached the repo.