# Failed to send stats: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A: sslv3 alert handshake failure

Tags: openssl, cocoapods

My development environment is `gem --version(2.0.14)`, `pod --version(0.38.2)`. While installing the third party libs using CocoaPods，

```
pod install --verbose --no-update
```

I got an error as following:

```
  Preparing

Analyzing dependencies

Inspecting targets to integrate
  Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods`: (``)

Finding Podfile changes
  - AFNetworking
  - Masonry
  - NIMSDK

Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`

Comparing resolved specification to the sandbox manifest
  - AFNetworking
  - Masonry
  - NIMSDK

Downloading dependencies

-> Using AFNetworking (2.5.4)

-> Using Masonry (0.6.2)

-> Using NIMSDK (1.2.0)
  - Running pre install hooks

Generating Pods project
  - Creating Pods project
  - Adding source files to Pods project
  - Adding frameworks to Pods project
  - Adding libraries to Pods project
  - Adding resources to Pods project
  - Linking headers
  - Installing targets
    - Installing target `AFNetworking` iOS 7.0
    - Installing target `Masonry` iOS 7.0
    - Installing target `Pods` iOS 7.0
  - Running post install hooks
  - Writing Xcode project file to `Pods/Pods.xcodeproj`
  - Writing Lockfile in `Podfile.lock`
  - Writing Manifest in `Pods/Manifest.lock`

Integrating client project

Integrating target `Pods` (`XXXX.xcodeproj` project)
  - Running post install hooks
    - cocoapods-stats from `/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-stats-0.5.3/lib/cocoapods_plugin.rb`

Sending stats
      - AFNetworking, 2.5.4
      - Masonry, 0.6.2
      - NIMSDK, 1.2.0
      Failed to send stats:  SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A: sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

I have tried to reinstall CocoaPods, but it's useless. And I also have searched the Internet trying to find a solution to the error, but there was no appropriate answer. Is there anyone knowing how to fix the problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I fixed the error by downgrading the CocoaPods to version 0.37. And after that the error disappeared! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20487849/downgrading-or-installing-older-version-of-cocoapods

Comment: I am using the latest cocoaPods 0.38.2 and still got this issue. So upgrading cocoaPods seems not the solution.

Comment: (⊙o⊙)…I downgraded CocoaPods, not upgraded it...

Comment: upgrading to 0.39 beta also fix it.

Comment: As far as I can tell this only causes their stats to be little off. Pods get installed just fine, so I'd just ignore it until it goes away once 0.39 comes out of beta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case (I was using 0.38.2), upgrading to `0.39.beta` fix the issue.

It seems that `cocoaPods` version `0.38.x` have bugs. When you perform `pod install` you'll always got this " *Failed to send stats:  SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A: sslv3 alert handshake failure* " tips.

Comment: FYI, I used the COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS environment variable to get around this issue on v0.38.2. Documented here: http://blog.cocoapods.org/Stats/

Answer (score 0):

When I used **pod install --verbose --no-update**,It was failed to send stats.But when I used **pod install**,It was worked.