# How to find if cocoaPods is installed in my mac

Tags: ios

Can anyone help to find if cocoaPod is installed in my machine. I was trying to use Google Map in my application. So i was asked to install CocoaPods. Could any one help me explain me the purpose.

Comment: Did you go to the cocoapods website and read about it?

Comment: Yes. I understood that it is used to manage and work with any libraries. I read that it is build through Ruby

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Solution found: Initially the Cocoapods has to be installed using the command `sudo gem install cocoapods` (I had some problem with proxies so it dint work for me initially and i resolved it).

To find if Cocoapods is installed or not run cmd (pod --version). if theresult is (Not Found) Pods is not installed. Please check for the internet connection and their proxies, these things took me huge time.

Answer (score 77):

try to find pod version by running this in terminal

```
pod --version
```

If command not found then you didn't installed

To install cocoapods

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Reference : https://cocoapods.org

Comment: ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'cocoapod' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - Errno::ETIMEDOUT: Operation timed out - connect(2) (https://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)

Comment: If you want to install specific version https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20487849/how-to-downgrade-or-install-an-older-version-of-cocoapods

Comment: When I run pod --version, I get bad interpreter

Answer (score 0):

Enter this line and see if you get error:

```
 pod search realm
```

Comment: @ragulml so you didn't have installed.