# Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1 and Embedded pods framework

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, alamofire, code-signing

Not able to identified actual issue, During updating coco pod getting a message "**Re-creating CocoaPods due to major version update.**"
 (that was come only once) and pod updation is successful. After on build i am getting the error. **Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1**. 
Below is some detail also which i am getting

1. `Code Signing /Users/Gaurav/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Appname-******/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Appname.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework with Identity iPhone Developer: Account Name (Account Id)`
2. `/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign *****************  --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements "/Users/UserName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Appname-***************/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Appname.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework"`
3. `/Users/Username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Appname-************/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Appname.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework: bundle format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable`

I'm using iOS 8 as deployment target and Xcode 7.3.1
I have checked code signing identity that doesn't have any issue. I have reinstall again all pod and Alamofire also but not abel to identified issue.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Clean the project, and deleting the derived data (~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/) fixed it for me

Comment: Yes, I already got the same answer form somewhere. but thanks for effort.

Comment: This did it for me:

In Xcode go to Window > Projects > *Select your project > Click "Delete" next to "Derived Data"

Comment: File > Project Settings > Click the arrow next to the folder, then delete the "Derived Data"

Answer (score 5):

If it was complaining about a particular Pod and being unable to codesign it.

Below things work for me:

1. Select the Pods Project In the main editor window, select the Pod in
   the targets dropdown
2. Under the general tab, and under the identity header, click choose
   Info.plist file
3. Select the plist file for the Pod

The project should now build. For some reason, it seems to lose this setting, or not be able to reference it's own plist file.

Not 100% sure but I hope it helps someone.

Comment: there is no 'choose info.plist file" option, at least not in Xcode 9

Answer (score 3):

I have the same issue. It happen after updating cocoaPods, so I just downgrading it and all works fine. I think we just need to wait for a new version of cocoaPods and for now you can use old version.
[How to downgrade cocoaPods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20487849/downgrading-or-installing-older-version-of-cocoapods)