# How to switch cocoapod version

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cocoapods

My system contain more than cocoapod version(like cocoapods (1.2.0, 1.1.1, 1.0.1, 1.0.0, 0.39.0, 0.38.2)).I want to switch to 0.39.0 version.
How to switch to this specified version?

Comment: are you using a gemfile?

Comment: no i amusing only podfile

Comment: Any reason you can't just use the newest version? If not then just uninstall all and reinstall version 0.39.0 like Brijesh said

Comment: @Bryan My mac contain latest pod version,but I want to switch to older version because my xcode project podfile.lock contain older cocoapod version.

Comment: Have you tried  `pod _0.39.0_ setup`? Found from [https://stackoverflow.com/a/31772875/5470541](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31772875/5470541)

Comment: @Bryan Its not working for me

Comment: @JAK : did my answer  helped you ?

Answer (score 20):

first remove the current cocoapod version as

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
```

and then install the version what you want 
as

```
sudo gem install cocoapods -v 0.39.0
```

Comment: I already installed it.But need to only switch between different versions..

Answer (score 14):

You can run `install` command by specifying the  version of cocoapods . like below .

```
pod _0.38.2_ install
```

or

```
pod _0.39.0_ install
```

you can also run other command like `setup` and other just like above .

I hope this will help you to switch to this specified version of cocopods :)

Answer (score 7):

see this [Managing Ruby Tools with Bundler](http://www.mokacoding.com/blog/ruby-for-ios-developers-bundler/)

create a ne textfile called `Gemfile` in the same folder as your project

it contains

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'cocoapods', '0.39.0'
```

you also need to have installed `bundler`

```
$ gem install bundler
```

after that enter the following command in your terminal at the project level

```
$ bundle install
$ bundle exec pod install
```

now only the pod version defined in you Gemfile and the pod versions defined in your podfile should be used, not the global ones.

Answer (score 3):

You can specify the version of the Cocoapods you want to use directly after the `pod` command: `pod _0.39.0_ setup`

Answer (score 2):

Install specific version with this command example,

```
sudo gem install cocoapods -v 0.39.0
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods -v 0.39.0
```

Answer (score -1):

Switch 1.7.5 to 1.7.0 :))

```
Last login: Mon Aug 19 10:24:50 on ttys000
 ~  pod --version
1.7.5
 ~  gem list cocoapods

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

cocoapods (1.7.5, 1.7.0, 1.5.3, 1.1.1)
cocoapods-core (1.8.0.beta.1, 1.7.5, 1.7.0, 1.6.1, 1.5.3, 1.3.1, 1.2.1, 1.1.1)
cocoapods-deintegrate (1.0.4, 1.0.2, 1.0.1)
cocoapods-downloader (1.2.2, 1.1.3, 1.1.2)
cocoapods-plugins (1.0.0)
cocoapods-search (1.0.0)
cocoapods-stats (1.0.0)
cocoapods-trunk (1.3.1, 1.2.0, 1.1.1)
cocoapods-try (1.1.0)
 ~  gem uninstall cocoapods -v 1.7.5
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::InstallError)
    cocoapods is not installed in GEM_HOME, try:
    gem uninstall -i /Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global cocoapods
 ~  sudo gem uninstall cocoapods -v 1.7.5
Password:
Successfully uninstalled cocoapods-1.7.5
 ~  gem list cocoapods

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

cocoapods (1.7.0, 1.5.3, 1.1.1)
cocoapods-core (1.8.0.beta.1, 1.7.5, 1.7.0, 1.6.1, 1.5.3, 1.3.1, 1.2.1, 1.1.1)
cocoapods-deintegrate (1.0.4, 1.0.2, 1.0.1)
cocoapods-downloader (1.2.2, 1.1.3, 1.1.2)
cocoapods-plugins (1.0.0)
cocoapods-search (1.0.0)
cocoapods-stats (1.0.0)
cocoapods-trunk (1.3.1, 1.2.0, 1.1.1)
cocoapods-try (1.1.0)
 ~  pod --version
1.7.0
```

Comment: This is not switching at all.