# Cocoapods issue while running your project on lower versions of Xcode or older macbooks

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, cocoapods, version

I am having 2 Macbook systems, one of which contains OSX Yosemite (with Xcode 6.2) and the other one has the new macOS Sierra (with Xcode 9.2).
I tried to install cocoapods through new machine (the one with Xcode 9.2) and binded it to my Xcode project.

I was able to build and run the project successfully. But when I try to run the same project in older machine (with Xcode 6.2) it gives me pods error.

I tried to reinstall the pods on that older machine, but the errors are still there. I am not getting what to do. Here is the screen shot of errors which I get while running the Xcode project on older machine

[image: Cocoapods error image]

What should I be doing to get rid of these errors?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning build forlder of project before running ?

Comment: Why should you want to run your project with Xcode 6.2 as apple will accept the binaries built with minimum Xcode 7, and this is just because of cocoapods version issue

Comment: @PPL its because , we are 2 people working on ios. So we need to work on the same project on these 2 machine.  So is there any solution for it??

Comment: @PPL can you tell me how to install cocoapods with a version that is compatible with xcode version 6.2, so that i will be atleast  able run the project for  testing purpose. please help me

Comment: @Coder i did tried cleaning it, but no success. Is there another way to get rid of it?

Comment: @Muju Please see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20487849/how-to-downgrade-or-install-an-older-version-of-cocoapods

Comment: make sure your in the .xcodeworkspace

Comment: install xcode 9 also to the another mac... so you both can work simultaneously.