# "You don't have write permissions for the /usr/bin directory." when installing Sass using the Gem command

Tags: macos, terminal, sass, rubygems

I'm on Mac and I'm trying to install Sass using the command in terminal, "sudo gem install sass".  I then enter my password, and everything works fine until this pops up,

"ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /usr/bin directory."

I do use sudo, but it still doesn't work, and it's one of those things that you can't give yourself read & write permissions to.  Any ideas?

Thanks,

Wade

Answer (score 113):

`/usr/bin` is protected by system integrity protection and is not writeable by 
anybody even root. You need to run:

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin sass
```

to install into a writeable directory

Comment: I'm not sure this is the best solution. What if you want to install it system wide?

Comment: @Dimitri /usr/local is system wide, it's where you are supposed to install software on mac os, there is no way to write to /usr/bin without disabling sip

Comment: @AlanBirtles I installed it using your command but Rails thinks the gem is missing. How to say it the gem is installed somewhere else?

Comment: You could try setting the `GEM_PATH` environment variable

Comment: Why does it use `/usr/bin` by default if it will never work?

Comment: @trapper presumably its just installing to the same place as ruby itself is installed

Answer (score 14):

For generamba:

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin generamba
```

Comment: What is **generamba**?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky, it's a code generator tool: https://github.com/strongself/Generamba

Answer (score 5):

For CocoaPods:

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```

Answer (score 4):

I used the same for bundler.

sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin bundler.

It works.