# Catalina Pod update issue: (while checking pod version)

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, macos-catalina

- `sudo gem install cocoapods` (I have done)

while checking, `pod --version` : I am getting following issue:

> -i*Mac:~ bandishkumar$ pod --version
>   -bash: /usr/local/bin/pod: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter:*** 
>   No such file or directory

Comment: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57843280/5175709). Basically try doing: `sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods` so that it would install in the correct directory

Comment: working fine here

Answer (score 0):

So, I have the same problem. Cocoapods was not finding my Ruby version.
Instead of doing this:

> `sudo gem install cocoapods`

You should do:

> `sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods`