# Error installing nokogiri: Failed to build gem native extension & libiconv is missing (OSX)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri, homebrew, osx-yosemite

I try to clone [this repo](https://github.com/crowdint/acts_as_shopping_cart_app) and run `bundle install`. The bundle process failed and throw this error:

```
    ...
    Installing nokogiri 1.6.2.1 with native extensions
    Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.

    Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/zulhilmizainudin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20151130-43880-pntnc6.rb extconf.rb
    Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.
    -----
    libiconv is missing.  please visit http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html for help with installing dependencies.
    -----
    *** extconf.rb failed ***
    Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
    libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
    need configuration options.

    Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/Users/zulhilmizainudin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
        --help
        --clean
        --use-system-libraries
        --enable-static
        --disable-static
        --with-zlib-dir
        --without-zlib-dir
        --with-zlib-include
        --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
        --with-zlib-lib
        --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
        --enable-cross-build
        --disable-cross-build

    extconf failed, exit code 1

    Gem files will remain installed in /Users/zulhilmizainudin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.2.1 for inspection.
    Results logged to /Users/zulhilmizainudin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.2.0-static/nokogiri-1.6.2.1/gem_make.out
    An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.6.2.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
    Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.2.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Then I try to run this:

```
gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.2.1'
```

And now I get this error:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.
ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/zulhilmizainudin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20151130-43942-1axq4sj.rb extconf.rb
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.
-----
libiconv is missing.  please visit http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html for help with installing dependencies.
-----
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/zulhilmizainudin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --help
    --clean
    --use-system-libraries
    --enable-static
    --disable-static
    --with-zlib-dir
    --without-zlib-dir
    --with-zlib-include
    --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
    --with-zlib-lib
    --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
    --enable-cross-build
    --disable-cross-build

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/zulhilmizainudin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.2.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/zulhilmizainudin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.2.0-static/nokogiri-1.6.2.1/gem_make.out
```

I tried to follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6163052/1577357) but I still get the same error above.

I also try to uninstall and install my brew again ([based on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22439835/1577357)) and it's still same.

Also, I try [this solution](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/wiki/Install-libiconv-on-OS-X-with-Homebrew) but still get the error.

What should I do now to make sure this nokogiri gem installed successfully?

Note: I'm using OSX 10.11.1 El Capitan.

Comment: Do you have already installed  `xcode` ? What's the output of command `xcode-select --install` ? Also have you check the [nokogiri OSX installation instruction](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html#mac_os_x)?

Comment: Yes, I already install xcode and run `xcode-select --install`. The xcode developer tools installed successfully.

Comment: What led everyone to know the error involved xcode?

Comment: @JeremyThomas I would like to know too.

Answer (score 121):

Run these commands:

```
gem uninstall nokogiri
xcode-select --install
gem install nokogiri
```

source: http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html#mac_os_x

sometimes mac updates can break xcode CLI so reinstalling can fix the issue:
https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/1445

Comment: related answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19643153/error-to-install-nokogiri-on-osx-10-9-maverick

Comment: You are the best! Thank you for this!

Comment: Thanks for this. I actually has to update my MacOS version to Catalina before `xcode-select --install` was allowed to run!

Answer (score 32):

What worked for me (on **macOS Sierra**) was a combination of [Sam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39905467/3498950) and the following:

```
gem install nokogiri -- --with-xml2-include=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk/usr/include/libxml2 --use-system-libraries
```

Comment: This worked for me trying to install nokogiri -v 1.8.0

Comment: I used the same thing to install rails and it worked! Thanks.

Comment: this worked for me, just make sure to confirm the folder because mine was /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/include/libxml2

Answer (score 30):

I had a similar issue with `1.6.7.2` when `bundle install`ing on codeship with ruby 2.3.

What worked for me was adding:

`bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries`

before

`bundle install`

Comment: This is the best way to fix the problem in a more permanent solution.

    gem install nokogiri -v 1.6.6.2 -- --use-system-libraries

Comment: Yes, `gem install nokogiri -v 1.6.6 -- --use-system-libraries` seems to work

Answer (score 20):

If you're using bundle:

```
brew install libxml2

# If using Bundle
bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries \
  --with-xml2-include=$(brew --prefix libxml2)/include/libxml2
bundle install
```

from http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html

Comment: Excellent, this is what worked for me on High Sierra after trying everything above.

Comment: Wow. This is the only thing that worked for me. Thank you for sharing this Andy (all the way back in 2017 too!)

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you.

Answer (score 13):

**Try this**

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential patch ruby-dev zlib1g-dev liblzma-dev
```

**And then install Nokogiri**

```
sudo gem install nokogiri
```

Comment: cha-ching!  thx for this.  got me over the hump on `ubuntu 18.04`

Comment: Avoid installing any ruby libraries. You should be using `rvm` and therefore `ruby-dev` is not needed to be installed.

Answer (score 10):

I did everything in the other answers, but had to do one more thing:

1. Open Xcode
2. Click "Agree"
3. Wait a bit, close Xcode
4. Rejoice

Answer (score 6):

Seems like this is due to nokogiri `1.6.2.1` specific problem.

I add this inside my Gemfile:

```
gem 'nokogiri', '~> 1.6', '>= 1.6.7'
```

And run `bundle update nokogiri` and then `bundle`. Everything now working fine.

Answer (score 2):

It may also be an issue with the anaconda version of some of the libs.

```
$ conda deactivate
$ gem uninstall nokogiri
$ gem install nokogiri
$ conda activate base
```

worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar issue. The reason was outdated `xcode`.

If you run `brew doctor` you might see it. Just open `AppStore`, got to `updates` tab and update your xcode.

Comment: `brew doctor` told me about newer Command Line Tools release and gave instructions on how to force update it. That solved the problem for me:

`sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools && sudo xcode-select --install`

Answer (score 1):

[Spencer's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41491487/8060919) answer worked for me, but I also needed to use the -n parameter to overcome the permission issue documented [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893889/how-do-i-fix-the-you-dont-have-write-permissions-into-the-usr-bin-directory)

So in the end, the command that worked for me was:

```
gem install -n /usr/local/bin nokogiri -- --with-xml2-include=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/libxml2 --use-system-libraries
```

Comment: NEVER install gems as sudo

Answer (score 1):

If nothing above works,
Try deleting `Gemfile.lock`, and do reinstalling of gems.

Comment: You should be careful deleting `Gemfile.lock`. Not only will you reinstall the gems. But executing `bundle install` will update the versions of those gems

Comment: Deleting the `Gemfile.lock` file helped me fix the issue after installing Nokogiri natively as instructed on [Nokogiri official website](https://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html)

Answer (score 0):

Deleting nokogiri in rbenv gem folder and reinstalling solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while updating to xcode 10. I resolved it with the following steps :

1. xcode-select --install
2. bundle install --deployment
3. gem install nokogiri

Answer (score 0):

This helped me fix this

- I reinstalled Xcode and directed xcode-select to its path

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

ref: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17980786/3861525

Answer (score -1):

[Github Answer](https://github.com/reenhanced/gitreflow/issues/178#issuecomment-430423441)

```
sudo installer -pkg /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg -target /

bundle install
```