# How to fix error while trying to install Rails with RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, nokogiri

I'm trying to install Rails with RVM using the newest version of Ruby but I'm running with a problem when installing Nokogiri.

I already have some RVM gemsets that use Ruby 2.4.0 and I didn't have an issue. I installed Ruby 2.4.1 with:

```
rvm install ruby-2.4.0
```

And created a new gemset with:

```
rvm use ruby-2.4.1@quiniela --create
```

And then ran:

```
gem install rails --pre
```

And I got this error:

```
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/andres/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@quiniela/gems/nokogiri-1.7.1/ext/nokogiri
/Users/andres/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20170325-50295-1sw75cw.rb extconf.rb
checking if the C compiler accepts ... yes
checking if the C compiler accepts -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future... no
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.
Using mini_portile version 2.1.0
checking for iconv.h... yes
checking for gzdopen() in -lz... yes
checking for iconv using --with-opt-* flags... yes
```

And then:

```
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/andres/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --help
    --clean
    --use-system-libraries
    --enable-static
    --disable-static
    --with-zlib-dir
    --without-zlib-dir
    --with-zlib-include
    --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
    --with-zlib-lib
    --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
    --enable-cross-build
    --disable-cross-build
/Users/andres/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@quiniela/gems/mini_portile2-2.1.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:366:in `block in execute': Failed to complete compile task (RuntimeError)
    from /Users/andres/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@quiniela/gems/mini_portile2-2.1.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:337:in `chdir'
    from /Users/andres/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@quiniela/gems/mini_portile2-2.1.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:337:in `execute'
    from /Users/andres/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@quiniela/gems/mini_portile2-2.1.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:111:in `compile'
    from /Users/andres/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@quiniela/gems/mini_portile2-2.1.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:150:in `cook'
    from extconf.rb:364:in `block (2 levels) in process_recipe'
    from extconf.rb:257:in `block in chdir_for_build'
    from extconf.rb:256:in `chdir'
    from extconf.rb:256:in `chdir_for_build'
    from extconf.rb:363:in `block in process_recipe'
    from extconf.rb:262:in `tap'
    from extconf.rb:262:in `process_recipe'
    from extconf.rb:547:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /Users/andres/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@quiniela/extensions/x86_64-darwin-16/2.4.0/nokogiri-1.7.1/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1
```

It seems that it's a problem with Nokogiri.

I followed the suggestions in "[Error installing nokogiri: Failed to build gem native extension & libiconv is missing (OSX)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33996523/error-installing-nokogiri-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension-libiconv-is-mi)" without success.

I updated RVM and ran `gem update` but it didn't work. Xcode is updated as well.

Has anyone run into this problem?

Comment: You can't install Ruby 2.4.1 using `rvm install ruby-2.4.0 `. What does   /Users/andres/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@quiniela/extensions/x86_64-darwin-16/2.4.0/nokogiri-1.7.1/mkmf.log say the problem is? What did you do when you updated Xcode? Did you reinstall the command-line options?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

gem install nokogiri -- --with-xml2-include=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk/usr/include/libxml2 --use-system-libraries

It solved the problem for me ...