# find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem bundler (>= 0.a) (Gem::GemNotFoundException)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundle, jekyll

I used `sudo bundle install` and that might be the cause of the issue?

Now I have:

- `gem -v` 2.6.14
- `ruby -v` ruby 2.3.5p376 (2017-09-14 revision 59905) [x86_64-darwin15]
- `jekyll -v` jekyll 3.6.2
- `bundle -v`Bundler version 1.16.0.pre.3

I'm getting the following error when trying to run `bundle exec jekyll serve` or just `jekyll serve`

```
/Users/myusername/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:271:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem bundler (>= 0.a) (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
    from /Users/myusername/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:299:in `activate_bin_path'
    from /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.5/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
    from /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.5/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.5/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<MacBooMacBook-MacBook-MacBook-Pro-MacBook-PrMacBook-MacBooMacBMaMacBMaMaMaMaMaMaMaMaMacBMaMaMaMacBMa
```

Also, when accessing the folder in which I have my blog `cd my_path` I get the following message:

> VM used your Gemfile for selecting Ruby, it is all fine - Heroku does that too,
>   you can ignore these warnings with 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore /Library/WebServer/Documents/blog/Gemfile'.
>   To ignore the warning for all files run 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore allGemfiles'.
>   Unknown ruby interpreter version (do not know how to handle): RUBY_VERSION.

I've no idea how to solve this. I just want to create my static blog and honestly I have no idea about Ruby, Gem or Bundle :) So I would appreciate some insights!

Comment: Can this help maybe: https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/1860

Comment: @Cyzanfar thanks for that! I tried it, now got a new error on the process: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47035080/unknown-ruby-interpreter-version-do-not-know-how-to-handle-ruby-version

Answer (score 416):

The problem in my case is that the `Gemfile.lock` file had a `BUNDLED_WITH` version of `1.16.1` and `gem install bundler` installed version `2.0.1`, so there was a version mismatch when looking to right the folder

`gem install bundler -v 1.16.1` fixed it

Of course, you can also change your `Gemfile.lock`'s `BUNDLED_WITH` with last `bundler` version and use recent software, as [Sam3000](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5849539/sam3000) suggests

Comment: As an alternative, you may wish to change the `BUNDLED_WITH` version to the latest version of bundler. This worked for me and also saved me needing outdated software :)

Comment: Bundler 2 just got released, so if you are not specifying as above in your Dockerfile, you are going to hit this error https://bundler.io/blog/2019/01/03/announcing-bundler-2.html

Comment: Hi @antonio-tapiador I'm having this issue, but i'm on windows (can't switch to linux).
I've run 
`gem install bundler -v 1.16.1`
and now if aI run 
`gem.bat list bundler` 
I get bundler (2.0.1, 1.16.1, 1.9.6). 
I cant change the current version: executing `bundle.bat _1.16.1 install`
gives me this error: `Could not find command "_1.16.1"`. Do you have any idea, so I don't have to create a new question? Thanks!

Comment: Never mind, I was missing an underscore at the end of the version.

Comment: Thanks. This also solve my  same problem using ruby v2.5.1p57

Comment: For CI, I'm now using `bundler_version=$(grep -A 1 'BUNDLED WITH' Gemfile.lock | grep -o -P "[\d.]+"); gem install bundler -v $bundler_version` to dynamically install the version needed.

Comment: I'm getting `You don't have write permissions for the /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0 directory.` while executing the `gem install bundler`. Even with sudo. any idea?

Answer (score 148):

```
gem update --system
```

will update the rubygems and will fix the problem.

Comment: Just to clarify - as @noraj points out - the problem was introduced in the new version of bundler. If you follow the link, the solution is to update RubyGems.

Comment: `gem update --system` worked for me: `ruby` **2.5.0**, `bundler` **2.0.1**, `macOS` **10.13.6**.

Comment: @ReggieB: What link?

Comment: @Teekin https://bundler.io/blog/2019/01/04/an-update-on-the-bundler-2-release.html

Comment: this command actually created this issue for me!

Answer (score 103):

## Update:

According @noraj's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54083113/5790492) and @Niels Kristian's comment, the following command should do the job.

```
gem update --system
bundle install
```

---

I wrote this in case someone gets into an issue like mine.

`gem install bundler` shows that everythings installs well.

```
Fetching: bundler-1.16.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed bundler-1.16.0
Parsing documentation for bundler-1.16.0
Installing ri documentation for bundler-1.16.0
Done installing documentation for bundler after 7 seconds
1 gem installed
```

When I typed `bundle` there was an error:

```
/Users/nikkov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/bin/bundle:23:in `load': cannot load such file -- /Users/nikkov/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0/exe/bundle (LoadError)
    from /Users/nikkov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
    from /Users/nikkov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /Users/nikkov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

And in the folder `/Users/nikkov/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/` there wasn't a `bundler-1.16.0` folder.

I **fixed** this with `sudo gem install bundler`

Comment: After you "fix" it, make sure you fix your directory permissions on .rvm and .gem

Comment: @humanity explain more detailed please, buy editing my answer

Comment: @humanity chrs for your answer - would you pls be able to elaborate what you mean by fix your directory permissions on .rvm and .gem?

Comment: @Nik kov the location of .rvm and .gem folders are probably inside your home folder. Try to change the permissions of them by chmod command. It worked for me.

Comment: What @souravirus said...  Permissions need to be open enough on those directories, else failure.

Comment: Would love for someone to elaborate on what chmod permissions they granted here that worked.

Comment: sudo gem install is bad practice, in normal case all gem install should work without sudo

Answer (score 60):

This fixed it:

1. Remove Gemfile.lock `rm Gemfile.lock`
2. run `bundle install` again

EDIT: DON'T DO IT IN PRODUCTION!

For production go to this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54083113/revisions

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio Code and uploading and publishing via  Azure Devops, which is where it was failing on Build.,  I just deleted the lock file locally, committed and then pushed.  The Build was failing on the **Install Gems** step but now it works.

Comment: For an existing production project this is a terrible idea. You will end up installing a bunch of untested (with your system) new code.

Comment: Yes, this is a bad idea and should not be considered a fix. It does prove that the other answer (about having a mismatched Bundler version) is correct. Installing the correct version of Bundler should fix it.

Comment: Thanks @RobinDaugherty, I've edited the answer to warn everyone not to do it in production.

Comment: This shouldn't be done in development either. There's a good reason for the lock file, it shouldn't be deleted in an existing project. [Installing the correct version of bundler on your machine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60906902/1589422) fixes the problem, deleting `Gemfile.lock` should be considered a last resort since it can lead to other problems.

Answer (score 34):

The real answer is here if you try to install bundler 2.0.1 or 2.0.0 due to Bundler requiring RubyGems v3.0.0

> Yesterday I released Bundler 2.0 that introduced a number of breaking changes. One of the those changes was setting Bundler to require RubyGems v3.0.0. After making the release, it has become clear that lots of our users are running into issues with Bundler 2 requiring a really new version of RubyGems.
>
> We have been listening closely to feedback from users and have decided to relax the RubyGems requirement to v2.5.0 at minimum. We have released a new Bundler version, v2.0.1, that adjusts this requirement.

For more info, see: https://bundler.io/blog/2019/01/04/an-update-on-the-bundler-2-release.html

Comment: Thanks, your link saved me some time from googling the problem

Comment: Capistrano was failing on a new machine but not old ones. This fixed the issue for me.

Comment: It can't be "the real answer" to the OP's question because Bundler 2.0 didn't exist in 2017, although people will certainly find this page because the symptoms are the same.

Comment: I am experiencing the problem with bundler 2.0.1

Comment: Here are other breaking changes in version 2.0.0: https://github.com/bundler/bundler/releases/tag/v2.0.0

Answer (score 23):

The reason is your current ruby environment, you got a different version of bundler with the version in `Gemfile.lock`.

- Safe way, install bundler with the same version in `Gemfile.lock`, this won't break anything if there is some incampatibly thing happened.
- Hard way, just remove `Gemfile.lock`, and run `bundle install`.

Comment: Thanks for that. Definitely everybody should use the *safe* version to don't mess up the environment with newly *untested* gems. To install bundler with specific version e.g. `1.17` use `gem install bundler -v 1.17`

Answer (score 18):

to install bundler that matches with your `Gemfile.lock` use:

```sh
gem install bundler -v "$(grep -A 1 "BUNDLED WITH" Gemfile.lock | tail -n 1)"
```

Comment: This fixed it for me. Ultimately, install the expected bundler. Simples

Answer (score 12):

If you changed the ruby version you're using with `rvm use`, remove Gemfile.lock and try again.

Answer (score 5):

Open Gemfile.lock, which is to be found in the root of your app folder. Scroll to the end of the file and see the bundler version used. Then you make sure you install the bundler version used:

```
gem install bundler -v x.xx.xx
```

Or - delete the Gemfile.lock and bundle if you have higher bundler version installed.

The choice is yours, my friend.

Comment: I would not recommend deleting the Gemfile.lock because that would also update all gems. This can lead to huge problems.

Comment: @SandroL - totally agree with your statement. However, it is an option to those who are risk takers and drawn to drama.

Comment: Thank you. Installing the version I had in the `Gemfile.lock` folder did the trick!

Answer (score 5):

Adding to the many answers, my problem stemmed from wanting to use the docker's ruby as a base, but then using rbenv on top. This screws up a lot of things.

I fixed it in this case by:

- The Gemfile.lock version did need updating - changing the "BUNDLED WITH" to the latest version did at one point change the error message, so may have been required
- in .bash_profile or .bashrc, unsetting the environment variables:

```
unset GEM_HOME
unset BUNDLE_PATH
```

After that, rbenv worked fine. Not sure how those env vars were getting loaded in the first place...

Comment: I hit the same issue. I was setting GEM_HOME, GEM_PATH and BUNDLE_PATH to `/gems` inside of my `docker-compose.yml`. Unsetting those and rebuilding fixed it, though I would prefer to figure out the nuance of setting these to `/gems` and still having things like `rails new ...` work...

Answer (score 4):

In my case the above suggestions did not work for me. Mine was little different scenario.

When i tried installing `bundler` using `gem install bundler` .. But i was getting

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0 directory.
```

then i tried using `sudo gem install bundler` then i was getting

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
  You don't have write permissions for the /usr/bin directory.
```

then i tried with `sudo gem install bundler -n /usr/local/bin` ( Just `/usr/bin` dint work in my case ).

And then successfully installed `bundler`

EDIT: I use MacOS, maybe `/usr/bin` din't work for me for that reason (https://stackoverflow.com/a/34989655/3786657 comment )

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue today. I solve this problem by removing any `PATH` in `.bashrc` for older `rvm`.

Comment: You save me I had export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" in my bashrc, I remove it and it works

Answer (score 1):

My problem was I'm using RVM and had the wrong Ruby version activated...

Hope this helps at least one person

Answer (score 1):

export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"

Answer (score -2):

I was getting this error when running `bin/dev`

```
bin/dev
/Users/st/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/rubygems.rb:265:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem foreman (>= 0.a) with executable foreman (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
    from /Users/st/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/rubygems.rb:284:in `activate_bin_path'
    from /Users/st/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/bin/foreman:25:in `<main>'
```

I tried a bunch of things, but what fixed it was simply:

```bash
gem install foreman
```

And now `bin/dev` works as expected again.

Answer (score -3):

I had to do `rake clean --force`.  Then did `gem install rake` and so forth.

Answer (score -3):

I downgraded ruby from 2.5.x to 2.4.x in my particular case.