# Unknown ruby interpreter version (do not know how to handle): RUBY_VERSION

Tags: ruby, jekyll, rvm

Trying to `rvm use .` in order to follow the instructions [in here](https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/1860#issuecomment-17342047) in an attempt to fix my messed up configuration, I get the following message in console:

> Unknown ruby interpreter version (do not know how to handle): RUBY_VERSION.
>   Could not determine which Ruby to use; . should contain .rvmrc or .versions.conf or .ruby-version or .rbfu-version or .rbenv-version, or an appropriate line in Gemfile.

Which I guess refers to the variable RUBY_VERSION in the Gemfile:

```
source "https://rubygems.org" 
ruby RUBY_VERSION
```

What should I do? I guess `RUBY_VERSION` variable has to be defined as a system variable ?

I'm just trying to use Jekyll.

## Extra info:

Now I have:

- `gem -v` 2.6.14
- `ruby -v` ruby 2.0.0p648 (2015-12-16 revision 53162) [universal.x86_64-darwin15]
- `jekyll -v` fails with a very long error.
- `bundle -v` Bundler version 1.14.4

Comment: Try adding `ruby '2.2.0'` to your gemfile (replacing RUBY_VERSION with the actual version). Let me know what you get then when you try to `bundle install`

Comment: I did, now I get `Required ruby-2.2.0 is not installed.`, even though using `ruby -v` returns me: `ruby 2.0.0p648 (2015-12-16 revision 53162) [universal.x86_64-darwin15]`

Comment: `rvm use 2.2.0` now ruby version should be version should be set to that version

Comment: @Cyzanfar using `rvm use 2.2.0` returns `Required ruby-2.2.0 is not installed. To install do: 'rvm install "ruby-2.2.0"'`

Comment: I added extra info in the question.

Comment: ok one last try haha.`rvm install ruby-2.2.0` then `rvm --default use ruby-2.2.0` to set the default version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RUBY_VERSION should be a specific version string, like '2.4.2' (with the quotes).

However, if you don't particularly care which Ruby version you use, then you should be able to just remove the whole line and rvm will use the default.

Comment: I tried both. Removing it won't work as it says: `Now using system ruby.
Could not determine which Ruby to use; . should contain .rvmrc or .versions.conf or .ruby-version or .rbfu-version or .rbenv-version, or an appropriate line in Gemfile.
Run `rvm help` to see usage information`

Comment: And using a number such as 'ruby 2.0.0' shows me: `Required ruby-2.2.0 is not installed. etc....` even though using `ruby -v` returns  `ruby 2.0.0p648 (2015-12-16 revision 53162) [universal.x86_64-darwin15]`

Comment: A couple of things to try: `rvm --default use system` to make sure rvm has a good fallback, then try setting the full version string in the file, '2.0.0p648'.

Comment: Both done, with  `rvm --default use system` I got the message "Now using system ruby." twice. But nothing changed.

Comment: Using the whole string `2.0.0p648` didn't change anything, still getting `Required ruby-2.0.0p648 is not installed. Could not determine which Ruby to use; . should contain .rvmrc or .versions.conf or .ruby-version or .rbfu-version or .rbenv-version, or an appropriate line in Gemfile.`

Comment: Maybe relevant to mention I also get this in yellow ? `RVM used your Gemfile for selecting Ruby, it is all fine - Heroku does that too,
you can ignore these warnings with 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore ./Gemfile'.
To ignore the warning for all files run 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore allGemfiles'.`

Comment: Maybe it's just not picking up the system ruby. Try `rvm install 2.4.2`, then use "2.4.2" in the gemfile, see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks that last thing solved the issue! Now I get another one. I opened this new question for it: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47046419/1081396

Comment: thanks @Alvaro & @Floppy -- the fix for me was `rvm use system` thank you!!!