# Could not find 'jekyll' (>= 0)

Tags: ruby, jekyll, rvm

Using `jekyll -v` returns the following:

> /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:308:in 'to_specs': Could not find 'jekyll' (>= 0) among 21 total gem(s) (Gem::MissingSpecError)
>   Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2:/Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2@global', execute 'gem env' for more information
>       from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:320:in 'to_spec'
>       from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:65:in 'gem'
>       from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:22:in `'

What's going on?

Comment: are you on windows?

Comment: `gem install jekyll`? Did you recently upgrade your RVM Ruby?

Comment: @xploshioOn on Mac

Comment: @Casper I did install rvm ruby recently as it was suggested to me in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47039723/1081396).
I've now tried `gem install jekyll` and now I got a new problem. I've created [a new issue for it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47046526/1081396). Please add your comment as a solution and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems that you don't have the jekyll gem installed, try installing it with

```
gem install jekyll
```

and remember that if you are using rvm, you need to select the version you will use in that terminal session,

```
rvm use x.x.x
```

or set the default, so everytime you open a terminal, then a version to use is set by default

```
rvm --default use x.x.x
```

Comment: Thanks! Done! But now I got [a new issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47046526/1081396).