# Jekyll -v error (Bundler::GemNotFound)

Tags: ruby, jekyll, rvm, bundler

When running `jekyll -v` I get the following:

```
/Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:88:in 'block in materialize': Could not find jekyll-feed-0.9.2 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
from /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:82:in 'map!'
from /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:82:in 'materialize'
from /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/definition.rb:170:in 'specs'
from /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/definition.rb:237:in 'specs_for'
from /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/definition.rb:226:in 'requested_specs'
from /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:108:in 'block in definition_method'
from /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:20:in 'setup'
from /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler.rb:107:in 'setup'
from /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/jekyll-3.6.2/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:50:in 'require_from_bundler'
from /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/jekyll-3.6.2/exe/jekyll:11:in '<top (required)>'
from /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/bin/jekyll:23:in 'load'
from /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/bin/jekyll:23:in '<main>'
from /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in 'eval'
from /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in '<main>'
```

## Update:

After using `gem install jekyll-feed` I get the following:

```
/Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:88:in 'block in materialize': Could not find minima-2.1.1 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
from /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:82:in 'map!'
from /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:82:in 'materialize'
from /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/definition.rb:170:in 'specs'
from /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/definition.rb:237:in 'specs_for'
from /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/definition.rb:226:in 'requested_specs'
from /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:108:in 'block in definition_method'
from /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:20:in 'setup'
from /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler.rb:107:in 'setup'
from /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/jekyll-3.6.2/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:50:in 'require_from_bundler'
from /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/jekyll-3.6.2/exe/jekyll:11:in '<top (required)>'
from /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/bin/jekyll:23:in 'load'
from /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/bin/jekyll:23:in '<main>'
from /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in 'eval'
from /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in '<main>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you don't have another gem installed, try with this to install it

```
gem install jekyll-feed
```

Comment: just see the part that is changing, it seems that it's not installing the dependencies for jekyll, so just change the gem name with next error until you finish to install all the dependencies, in this case, the last update, the gem is minima, so, gem install minima

Comment: and to be more specific, just add the version that is on the error, like
gem install minima -v 2.1.1, and keep on with the other errors if you get more

Comment: Just `gem install minima -v 2.1.1` got rid of all the other errors! Thanks for that!

Comment: Right now I'm having a new issue with using `jekyll serve`. I´ve created [a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47046746/1081396) about it.

Answer (score 1):

You're having a bunch of related issues around dependencies. To make sure it all works itself out, add a `Gemfile` with the contents:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

ruby "2.4.2"

gem 'github-pages' # helpfully pulls in more than just jekyll
```

and then run `bundle`. Then when you want to run jekyll, do `bundle exec jekyll`, and you should be fine.