# Jekyll serve error: can't find gem jekyll (>= 0.a) (Gem::GemNotFoundException

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll, rvm, bundler

When doing `sudo jekyll serve` I get the following error:

```
Users/myusername/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems.rb:271:in 'find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem jekyll (>= 0.a) (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
from /Users/myusername/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems.rb:299:in 'activate_bin_path'
from /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/bin/jekyll:23:in '<main>'
from /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in 'eval'
from /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in '<main>'
```

In case it helps:

- `jekyll -v` returns `jekyll 3.6.2`
- `ruby -v` returns `ruby 2.4.2p198 (2017-09-14 revision 59899) [x86_64-darwin15]`
- `gem -v` returns `2.6.14`
- `bundle -v` returns `Bundler version 1.16.0`

On my Gem file I have:

> ruby '2.4.2'

`rmv list` output:

```
ruby-2.3.5 [ x86_64 ]
=* ruby-2.4.2 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

Comment: try install specific 2.4.2 version of ruby 'rvm install 2.4.2', set it as default and then install the gems again and everything

Comment: I just did that a few minutes ago as per what I was suggested to do [here in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47039723/1081396).

Comment: `rvm --default use 2.4.2`?  How to install the gems and "everything" ? As you can see I'm quite lost here :)

Comment: rvm install 2.4.2, then, rvm --default use 2.4.2, gem install jekyll

Comment: I did that.  `rvm install 2.4.2` shows `Already installed ruby-2.4.2.`. I then did `rvm --default use 2.4.2` but doing `ruby -v` still showing the same as before `ruby 2.4.2p198 (2017-09-14 revision 59899) [x86_64-darwin15]`. I also did `gem install jekyll` but still having exactly the same issue when running `sudo jekyll serve`

Comment: post the output of 'rvm list'

Comment: Check it in the question. I updated it.

Comment: maybe the problem that you are facing is that you tried to install ruby before, without rvm, try removing everything about ruby, I don't have much experience with mac, but google 'how to remove ruby completely from mac' or something like that, then try again with the steps that I sent before, it should work

Comment: Ok thanks! I'll try tomorrow and let you know! :)

Comment: @xploshioOn according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4115803/1081396) and [this other one](https://superuser.com/questions/194051/how-to-completely-remove-ruby-ruby-gems-on-mac-os-x-10-6-4) we should never remove the system's Ruby. So... not quite sure how to proceed with the removal of the rvm ruby I installed. Any tips?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally solved it by doing:

```
sudo rm -rf _site
bundle update
bundle exec jekyll serve
```

And then always using `bundle exec jekyll serve` instead of `sudo jekyll serve` or `jekyll serve`.

I got this solution thanks to the answers [in this post](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/6510#issuecomment-341145757).