# Bundler: can't find gem bundler (>= 0.a) with executable bundle (Gem::GemNotFoundException) during bundle install with gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundle, bundler

I'm executing the following script:

```
gem install rdoc --no-document
gem install bundle
bundle
```

output:

```
+ gem install rdoc --no-document
Successfully installed rdoc-6.1.1
1 gem installed
+ gem install bundle
Successfully installed bundle-0.0.1
Parsing documentation for bundle-0.0.1
Done installing documentation for bundle after 2 seconds
1 gem installed
1 gem installed
+ bundle install
/usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:289:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem bundler (>= 0.a) with executable bundle (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:308:in `activate_bin_path'
    from /srv/myuser/.gem/ruby/2.5.0/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
```

I've added `/srv/myuser/.gem/ruby/2.5.0/bin` to my path so I was able to install gems.

the `gem env` shows

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.7.7
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.5.1 (2018-03-29 patchlevel 57) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /srv/myuser/.gem/ruby/2.5.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /srv/myuser/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0
     - /srv/myuser/.gem/ruby/2.5.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "gem" => "--user-install"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
```

`gem list` shows the installed gems.
I can also find bundle when I perform:

```
ls -ltrah /srv/myuser/.gem/ruby/2.5.0/bin
```

I've also tried to install bundler but that didn't also help.
What am I doing wrong?

`gem which bundle` is showing nothing.`gem spec bundle` is showing it.

Update: I tried to install bundler before running bundle but the same issue appears while:

`gem list bundle` shows

```
bundle (0.0.1)
bundler (2.0.1)
```

Answer (score 170, accepted):

Bundler version 2 introduced a new feature to automatically use the version of Bundler specified in the `Gemfile.lock` of your project. Thus, if you have an existing `Gemfile.lock` with a line like this at the bottom

```
BUNDLED WITH
   1.17.3
```

Bundler will try to run with a Bundler version < 2.0. Since you just have Bundler 2.0.1 (and Rubygems >= 2.7.0) installed, this fails with this rather unhelpful error message.

To fix this, you could

- remove the lines from your `Gemfile.lock` and to use bundler 2.x everywhere from now on, or
- install a bundler 1.x version with `gem install bundler -v '< 2.0'` to use the appropriate version as specified by your `Gemfile.lock`.

More information about this can be found on the [Bundler blog](https://bundler.io/blog/2019/01/04/an-update-on-the-bundler-2-release.html).

Comment: IMO This should be the correct answer. Another option to add to this list of possible fixes is to delete `Gemfile.lock` and run bundle install again

Comment: Thanks for this answer, saved me a lot of trying.

Comment: If one updates `rubygems` to newer version - it should solve the problem as well.
`gem update --system` to upgrade to latest version ( or at least `gem update --system '2.7.10' to stay on 2.7.x version of RubyGems`.

Comment: The Bundler blog provides an one-line command to install the exact version of Bundler that RubyGems is looking for:

```shell
gem install bundler -v "$(grep -A 1 "BUNDLED WITH" Gemfile.lock | tail -n 1)"
``` 

You can read [their article](https://bundler.io/blog/2019/05/14/solutions-for-cant-find-gem-bundler-with-executable-bundle.html) for more information.

Answer (score 96):

As per the description mentioned in the post , before running the below mentioned command:

```
bundle install
```

in the script, you need to run the below command:

```
gem install bundler
```

So, the sequence of commands to work would be:

```
gem install bundler
bundle install
```

Update the bundler command if if does not work to:

```
 gem install bundler -v '1.17.3'
```

Reason for the break in functionalities in bundler 2.0 is given in below mentioned link:

https://bundler.io/blog/2019/01/04/an-update-on-the-bundler-2-release.html

Comment: Tried it but still the same issue.

Comment: That did the trick wow!! You can update your answer and I'll accept it. Maybe you can provide some more info?

Comment: Updated the answer!!

Comment: Great answer, did not expect it to be as simple as reverting the version but it is nice to know it was.

Comment: If you have just upgraded from Bundler 1.x to 2.x, see the answer from Holger Just related to BUNDLED WITH. No need to downgrade your bundler. Removing the lines or updating to your current version resolves.

Answer (score 48):

I couldn’t even do `bundle -v`. This sorted it out:

```
gem update --system
```

Got the info from here (similar problem): [find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem bundler (>= 0.a) (Gem::GemNotFoundException)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47026174/find-spec-for-exe-cant-find-gem-bundler-0-a-gemgemnotfoundexception)

Probably some version mismatch between ruby + gem + bundler

Comment: This solved the issue for me and also [matches bundler's own docs](https://bundler.io/blog/2019/05/14/solutions-for-cant-find-gem-bundler-with-executable-bundle.html)

Answer (score 19):

```
gem install bundler -v '< 2.0'
```

Answer (score 9):

I faced this same issue. The issue is caused by the fact that RubyGems cannot find an executable bundle for the bundler gem on the system

To fix it, first run

`gem install bundler`

if you don't have bundler gem installed locally, then run

`gem update --system`

That's all

**I hope this helps**

Comment: `gem update --system -N` if stuck on installing documents to skip it

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem recently. 
In my case I have installed a version on bundler different from what is logged in the Gemfile.lock. Please check

Answer (score 4):

This may help solve the problem

```
bundle update --bundler
```

Comment: This fixed mine.

Answer (score 3):

You've to install the exact version of Bundler that RubyGems is looking for by running:

```
$ gem install bundler -v "$(grep -A 1 "BUNDLED WITH" Gemfile.lock | tail -n 1)"
```

Answer (score 1):

I just faced the same error today. The bundler version which I had installed in my system previously was: 1.16.6

Followed the instructions in the official bundler docs on [How to Upgrade to Bundler 2](https://bundler.io/v2.0/guides/bundler_2_upgrade.html) and the below two steps did the trick:

1. `gem install bundler` (Helps you get the latest version of bundler which as of today is 2.0.2)
2. `bundle update --bundler`

Answer (score 1):

I saw a similar error message for the travis bundle after upgrading mac os to Catalina.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    2: from /usr/local/bin/travis:22:in `<main>'
    1: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:263:in `bin_path'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:284:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem travis (>= 0.a) with executable travis (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
```

To resolve the issue, I reinstalled travis from source.

```
brew remove travis;
brew install -s travis
```

Answer (score 1):

YEP, this works:

`gem install bundler -v "$(grep -A 1 "BUNDLED WITH" Gemfile.lock | tail -n 1)"`

From: https://bundler.io/blog/2019/05/14/solutions-for-cant-find-gem-bundler-with-executable-bundle.html

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps an over-specific (and nooby) answer:

In RubyMine my project was set to Ruby 3.0.0
However, my terminal was using 2.7.6

I used RVM `rvm use 3.0.0` to set my terminal to 3.0.0
Problem solved