# Deploy Rails Project to Google App Engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm having a trouble while deploying a rails project to Google App Engine.

No matter what I do what I can do, I couldn't find any solution.

Below is what I face after executing a command 'gcloud app deploy'. Please tell me any way to fix it if you know some.

```html
Step #1: Removing intermediate container c8d1a2f4acc5
Step #1:  ---> 61448e13156f
Step #1: Step 11/16 : COPY . /app/
Step #1:  ---> 9bdc2877b562
Step #1: Step 12/16 : RUN bundle install --deployment --without="development test" && rbenv rehash
Step #1:  ---> Running in 8a6b6fe3c638
Step #1: /opt/rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:289:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem bundler (>= 0.a) with executable bundle (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
Step #1:  from /opt/rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:308:in `activate_bin_path'
Step #1:  from /opt/rbenv/versions/2.5.3/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
Step #1: The command '/bin/sh -c bundle install --deployment --without="development test" && rbenv rehash' returned a non-zero code: 1
Finished Step #1
ERROR
ERROR: build step 1 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker@sha256:cec0ad3c32ec7576acc49bf9348eb60ac9fa760a02ca7dd255e2c1b3f774efc3" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
Step #1: 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Did you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47026174/find-spec-for-exe-cant-find-gem-bundler-0-a-gemgemnotfoundexception ? If it helps.

Comment: By refering it, I've tried to change a [BUNDLE WITH] part in Gemlock.file and it worked. Thank you!